# SQL Update MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

**UPDATE calendar SET eventDays = null WHERE ??**

Problem:

168 eventDays | 24 weeks each day assigned a week number

if dayCount >=2 in a eventWeeks (24) remove eventDay for entire eventWeeks (7)

any eventWeek with total of just 1 would remove only that single date.

5/16/2017 to 5/22/2017 would remove date.

5/23/2017 to 5/29/2017 would just remove #5/24/2017#

do it for each group of eventWeeks (24)

```
eventDays | eventWeeks | dayCount
5/16/2017 | 1 | 1       
5/18/2017 | 1 | 0       
5/19/2017 | 1 | 0       
5/20/2017 | 1 | 0       
5/21/2017 | 1 | 1       
5/22/2017 | 1 | 0
5/23/2017 | 2 | 0       
5/24/2017 | 2 | 1       
5/25/2017 | 2 | 0       
5/26/2017 | 2 | 0       
5/27/2017 | 2 | 0       
5/28/2017 | 2 | 0       
5/29/2017 | 2 | 0
```

I tried several WHERE, HAVING and whatever, to no avail.

Comment: It's difficult to understand your requirements, but it seems like you might need to do this in a few passes, i.e. run a couple of update statements

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't aiming to delete those records?

Comment: To clarify, you want us to set the value of `eventDays` to `NULL` for an entire week where that week's total of `dayCount` is greater than or equal to `2` and otherwise to set the value of `eventDays` to `NULL` for any day with a `dayCount` of `1`?  Would you rather delete an entire record rather than set its `eventDays` value to `NULL`?

Comment: You are correct: also just delete that entire week if the day count >= 2 if that makes it easier. My client wants can only have 2 events per week, so if 2 people apply between tues and Monday remove the dates.

Comment: It's all tied to a third party Calendar which shows events (normal) Client is unnormal wants it "backwards completion principle".

Comment: Was that asked in pseudo-code or pseudo-english?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This calculates the `eventWeeks` to be deleted.

```
SELECT eventweeks FROM calendar WHERE daycount = 2 
UNION 
SELECT eventweeks FROM calendar WHERE daycount = 1 
  GROUP BY eventweeks HAVING SUM(daycount) = 2;
```

This deletes all days of every week for the weeks found.
This will not delete all days of a week, if `dayCount = 3`, as you requested.
And it will not delete all days of a week, if 3 days have `dayCount = 1` for a sum of 3, also by your request.

**Query F**

```
UPDATE calendar SET eventdays = NULL 
WHERE eventweeks IN (
  SELECT eventweeks FROM calendar WHERE daycount = 2 
  UNION 
  SELECT eventweeks FROM calendar WHERE daycount = 1 
    GROUP BY eventweeks HAVING SUM(daycount) = 2);
```

**Query F** behaviour is

```
eventWeeks | dayCount
    1      |     1    DELETE
    1      |     1    DELETE
    1      |     0    DELETE

    2      |     1    KEEP
    2      |     1    KEEP
    2      |     1    KEEP
    2      |     0    KEEP

    3      |     0    DELETE
    3      |     2    DELETE

    4      |     1    KEEP
    4      |     2    KEEP
```

**EDIT A**
Because MS Access 2000 does not seem to accept `UNION` in subqueries, here is an alternative `SELECT` query (see [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16551944/union-operation-not-allowed-in-sub-query-is-there-a-way-to-fix-this-in-one-sin)):

```
SELECT DISTINCT eventweeks FROM calendar x 
WHERE daycount = 2 
  OR EXISTS (
    SELECT y.eventweeks FROM calendar y 
    WHERE x.eventweeks = y.eventweeks AND y.daycount = 1 
    GROUP BY y.eventweeks HAVING SUM(y.eventweeks) = 2
);
```

And the appropriate `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE calendar SET eventdays = NULL 
WHERE eventweeks IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT eventweeks FROM calendar x 
  WHERE daycount = 2 
    OR EXISTS (
      SELECT y.eventweeks FROM calendar y 
      WHERE x.eventweeks = y.eventweeks AND y.daycount = 1 
      GROUP BY y.eventweeks HAVING SUM(y.eventweeks) = 2
  ));
```

Comment: You can use both WHERE to reduce the rows and then GROUP and check the group using HAVING with an aggregate function like COUNT. Example: 
SELECT eventweeks FROM calendar WHERE daycount >= 1 GROUP BY eventweeks HAVING COUNT(daycount) = 1;

Comment: Shouldn't that be `HAVING SUM( dayCount ) = 1`?

Comment: It depends on what you want. You can have SUM( dayCount ) = 2 with two rows with dayCount = 1 (1 + 1) or one single row with dayCount = 2. I think he wants dayCount at least one and then COUNT those that match. I don't quite understand his specification.

Comment: With a group of two values { 1, 2 }, we get SUM({ 1, 2 }) = 3, but COUNT({ 1, 2 }) = 2, not 3.

Comment: 2nd one: This sets null ALL eventdays for weeks... almost got it
Re: Question same day > Yes  Someone can book 2 events on the same in on a given week. Only missing that part, one date had 2 but did not delete.

Comment: You can use two queries to achieve your result.
Use "This sets null ALL eventdays for weeks" ... for the two days stuff.
And use "This sets null the single eventday for weeks" ... for the one day only stuff.
I will try to form the two into one single query.

Comment: Do you want to KEEP the dayCounts = 0 (equals zero) or do you want to DELETE them?
Do you want to delete all days, if two events have dayCount >= 1?
Or do you want only the events with dayCount >= 1 to be deleted?

Comment: Updated. Please see Edit: "This changes the last entry to dayCount = 2 for testing.". Is this ok? I know i can build what you want :)

Comment: Updated. Please see **EDIT 3**

Comment: Then **Query F** is what you are looking for. Please click the check mark next to the beginning of my answer to accept the solution. Also, please vote +1 by clicking ^ next to my answer.

Comment: Removed unneccessary parts of the answer to make the process faster. This is taking quite some time already...

Comment: I added another query, which does not use `UNION`, which MS Access 2000 does not seem to like in subqueries. Please check **EDIT A**. If it does still not work, please tell me. Now that the requirements are clear, it takes only minutes to write a new query.

Comment: Also, if the answer with **EDIT A** works, then please upvote it (triangle up; +1).

Comment: We used SQL= "UPDATE calendar SET eventdays = null WHERE eventWeeks IN ( SELECT eventWeeks FROM calendar WHERE dayCount >= 1 GROUP BY eventWeeks HAVING SUM(dayCount) >= 2);"
Decided not to save > then 2. Works thanks to your SUM. Answer OK and voted up.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
UPDATE calendar
SET eventDays = NULL
WHERE eventDays IN ( SELECT eventDays
                     FROM calendar
                     JOIN ( SELECT eventWeeks AS eventWeeks,
                                   SUM( dayCount ) AS daysCountSum
                            FROM calendar
                            GROUP BY eventWeeks
                          ) AS daysCounter ON calendar.eventWeeks = daysCounter.eventWeeks
                                          AND daysCounter.daysCountSum <= 1
                                          AND calendar.dayCount = 0
                   );
```

This statement works by first grouping all of the records in `calendar` by `eventWeeks` and calculating the total of `dayCount` for each group.  The results are then joined to calendar in such a way that `eventWeeks` who have a total of 2 or more for `dayCount` are omitted, and only those records that have a `0` value for `dayCount`are included.

The resulting data is then used to select which records from `calendar` are updated.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: Simples to be missing a closing bracket. add one to the end by got syntax error. Using MS Access